# How to Highlight Specific Cells that Meet Criteria or Filter it for Specific List

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have an excel sheet, and need to clean up the users within our database...I don't like using Excel, and was curios if there is anyway I can print a False or True column to see if an entry within a specific cell matches the other two columns plus a convention. The caveat is that all of the Username Logins need to match `firstname.lastname`, but not all of our users have that within the list of elements. As a result, I need to filter out the ones that do have it so I can see all of the users that do not have it.

[image]

As you can see there may be users within the `User Name` column that may not match the convention as a result I would like to have it print `FALSE` in Column I. This would allow me to have a filter and see all of the users that are misaligned within the database.

By the way I am forbidden to use any programmatic way or `SQL` update command on the database, so please limit suggestions on how to accomplish this in Excel.

Comment: Do you mean you just want check if Col A contains f and l ?

Comment: Maybe add the expected result in column I in your screenshot?

Comment: Formula for column I ... =A2=E2&"."&D2  .... and copy it down

Comment: Cool let me try it now.

Comment: Oh yeah Thanks @NareshBhople it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many Thanks to @Naresh Bhople

His formula

```
=A2=E2&"."&D2
```

Worked, then I just dragged and copied it all the way down to what I needed. 
It helped me clean up our Active Directory to get all of the systems working with AD Authentication and Kerberos Auth.